# asp.net identity authentication for simple registration -- asp.net mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, identity

I am about to start a project that needs custom identity authetication and authorization.

For authentication I am asking this question.

I need to know how can I create ExampleDBContext class that extends from DBContext class? and what settings I need to do in Startup.Auth.cs to make it work. And for registration, what should be the name of the registration table and what should be its columns? and what other tables and their columns need to be there?

There is  so much info related to identity authentication but nothing actually useful. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you want something like this:

**ExampleDbContext.cs**

```
public class ExampleDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IExampleDbContext
{
    public ExampleDbContext()
        : base("yourConnectionStringName", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ExampleDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ExampleDbContext();
    }



    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can use the code first method to generate the tables. That means that you can customize your User model the way you want. Here is the example of

**User.cs**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In the Users you can see that I've added some custom fields (FirstName LastName) and if you use the code first you can generate the custom Users table and use it for authentication. No need to add anything in `Startup.Auth.cs` you just need to setup dependency injection correctly.